# Blindfolded child told they have deadly powers associated with their vision

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

There exists a book that I have not read in years. In said book, the main character discovers they have deadly powers associated with their vision, and that since they are hard to control they must wear a blindfold for years. Their friend has animal taming powers, their father has the same power, and the setting appears to be medieval with serfs and farms.

At the end of the book, we learn that

> He was lied to and his powers were wimpy, and he gazes upon his mother when she is on her deathbed.

Answer (score 8):

Nevermind, I just didn't look hard enough. 3 Google pages later I found it. It's *[Gifts](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13648.Gifts)* (2004) by Ursula K. Le Guin.

[image: Book cover]

> Scattered among poor, desolate farms, the clans of the Uplands possess gifts. Wondrous gifts: the ability--with a glance, a gesture, a word--to summon animals, bring forth fire, move the land. Fearsome gifts: They can twist a limb, chain a mind, inflict a wasting illness. The Uplanders live in constant fear that one family might unleash its gift against another. Two young people, friends since childhood, decide not to use their gifts. One, a girl, refuses to bring animals to their death in the hunt. The other, a boy, wears a blindfold lest his eyes and his anger kill.